# converting large int list to byte string python

Tags: python, int, byte

I need to convert int list into a byte string but I don't know how. I can't use `bytes()` because the values are too large.

```
bytes([152710136, 76354857, 38177353, 2252736081, 1126368238])
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: bytes must be in range(0, 256)
```

The expected value is:

```
b'\xc4\xb7\x86\x17\xcd'
```

Comment: Specify what "byte string" means. Ascii-coded bytes as textual representation?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: If the values are less than 256 you can use bytes(list) and it will give you the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.to_bytes` to return an array of bytes representing an integer.
**Note**: This works only in python 3.1 and above.

For example:

```
>>> (1024).to_bytes(2, byteorder='big')
b'\x04\x00'
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to use struct.unpack() and it accepts a byte string rather than a list of ints. I was able to convert my list of ints to a byte string with:

```
bytearray(mylist)
```

Tested on python 2.7.